# Cross-Project References in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to reference a dll project from another project, and am encountering a few difficulties. I have done the following:

- Added both projects to a solution
- Within my executable project, I add the dll project as a reference.
- I add the include directory under Properties --> C/C++ --> Additional Include directories.

I thought this was sufficient - I don't get any errors, my intellisense is detecting the dll project and everything compiles. But when I run, I get the following system error messagebox:

> The program can't start because xxx.dll is missing from your computer.
>   Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

So I have tried adding the directory where the dll and lib files are built to to Reference Directories and Library Directories under VC++ Directories in the properties, but still get the same error.

Comment: You did not add a cross-project reference and you did not add a reference to the DLL.  You added a reference to the import library, keeps the linker happy.  This does not help the OS to find the DLL, copying the DLL into the right directory is something you'll have to take care of.  Use XCOPY in a post-build event.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have used xcopy as suggested to move the dll across and it all works, thanks. Just to further my understanding - I thought VC++ looks for dll files down the Reference Directories paths - if it doesn't do this, what is the Reference Directories path for?

Comment: It does not have anything to do with VC++.  It did its job, it built your program.  It is the OS that cannot find the DLL, it has no reason to look in the directory where it is stored.